# Chrome Apps <a> tag not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Its been a few years since I have worked on Chrome apps. I started messing around with making some simple examples to learn the new process. The problem is that I have found that using an `<a>` tag to change the html page that is loaded to another html page inside the packaged app will not work. I'm looking for different methods of changing the screen with retrieving user input (button click, link click. and so on). I have looked online and have found very little documentation about making chrome apps most examples show how to make a simple "Hello World" and how to publish it. Not many extensive tutorials beyond that. Just to clarify this app would be a real chrome app not a link to some site. all files would be packaged with the chrome application.

Comment: Define what you mean by "Will not work" - what is the expected behaviour and what is actually happening? Can you provide any code samples to replicate the problem?

Comment: The expected behavior for an '<a>' with a href pointing to a local file in the app would be that the page would change to that page. Like normal '<a>' behavior.

Comment: What is happening when you click on it? Nothing? Can we see some code?

Comment: I simply used a normal '<a>' tag with a local reference to another html file in the packaged app. When clicking on the link nothing happens. '<a href="localFile.html">click</a>' Nothing crazy just a normal <a> tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome Apps are meant to be ["single page apps"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), and cannot navigate links by design.  `<a>` links should open in a regular browser window instead.

If you want to do "url routing" within your application to change views, you *can* just roll your own solution, but should probably use a framework to help you out instead.

Here are some examples:

- Polymer
- Angular
- Ember
- Meteor
- Backbone

The list is extensive. There are likely many other stack overflow answers that compare each framework.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful but could you add in a few good examples of the frameworks being used in this fashion. The final answer should have good examples of a working solution so that others searching the site can get the information needed for the task without asking more questions.

Comment: Thanks to your answer i have looked up Angular and now see how to do it. but I think it would be helpful if you could link some good tutorials to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The DOM (Document Object Model) which represents the contents of a Chrome App window is initiated from an HTML file, but from that point on you can't change it by referencing any other file, which is what you're expecting navigation to do. (`<a>` elements that navigate to an external browser via a "target=_blank" attribute are perfectly OK.)

However, you are free to change the DOM from your JavaScript at runtime. If you like, set an event handler on the `<a>` element and change the DOM as you wish. If you want to change the DOM via HTML (not from a file), you might find the JavaScript method `insertAdjacentHTML` useful. Actually, you can get the HTML from a file, but you have to read that file yourself with the Chrome App file I/O API.

Advice in another answer to use a framework is, in my opinion, overkill. If you think of a Windows app, a Mac app, or any other kind of GUI-based app, you would never assume that you could just change the UI over to something completely different by referencing an HTML file. Think of a Chrome App as being similar to those technologies in that sense, and you'll be on the right track.

Comment: What if for example i want to make a grid menu and from selecting one of the items it would then bring me to another interface. Also not all but some desktop applications do change the interface based on user input. Due to the lack of examples on the internet for changing the interface in different ways it would be helpful if the final answer represents a good tutorial on how a user may use multiple good methods to interface changes and modifications. That way others can use the information provided on this post.

Comment: To provide a "good tutorial on how a user may use multiple good methods to interface changes and modifications" is a little too much to expect from a SO answer. I would think that setting you onto the right track would be sufficient. Sorry I was unable to satisfy your requirements.

Comment: No worries I just thought for the people that see the page after, It could help them out. I was able to find a lot of good tutorials based off the two answers and now able to accomplish the task.